# (Noob Coder) Basic Calculator Issue + Code Advice

Tags: java, oop, math, java.util.scanner, calculator

I am a learning Java, and as a personal project aside from my high school assignments, I decided to make some math solving programs for practice.

For a warm up, I decided to write a basic calculator program...and it works...kind of. So...please help me!

### Goal:

-> To have a calculator that, with Scanner input, can calculate any sequence of numbers with operators [+, -, /, ^(Math.pow), *]. (ex: 1+2+4+2, etc.)

### What works:

-> It can calculate the summation, product, power, difference, and divide two numbers (int or double, but answer is double).

### What doesn't work:

-> It cannot have input with any whitespace, or it will get an 'out of bounds' error on the first array (The summation one) and so on

-> It cannot calculate any compound problems (ex: 1+2+3, 3*4^6, etc.).

I plan on adding many other things to this (trig functions, extra powers, etc.), but for now, this needs work. Can someone tell me how to fix these problems?

### And most of all:

What are my biggest programming mistakes (other than it not working) that I should watch out for(based on the code you see)? I usually program by sequence and logic, but I feel that I (and my code) could be so much more efficient.

### The Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class basicCalculator {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    System.out.println("What would you like to calculate?");

    Scanner inputNum = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputI = inputNum.nextLine();
    Scanner inputScan = new Scanner(inputI);
    Scanner inputScan2 = inputScan.useDelimiter("\\+|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\^|\\s");
    Scanner inputScan3 = new Scanner(inputI);

    double textContent[] =  new double[1000];
    int loopCount = -1;
    int loopCount2 = 1;
    int loopCount3 = 0;
    double[] partOfResult = new double[1000];   

    while(inputScan.hasNextDouble()){
        loopCount++;
        textContent[loopCount] = inputScan.nextDouble();
    }

    while(inputScan3.hasNext()){
        if(inputI.contains("+")){
            partOfResult[loopCount3] = (textContent[loopCount2 - 1] + textContent[loopCount2]);
            loopCount3++;
            loopCount2++;
        }else if(inputI.contains("-")){ 
            partOfResult[loopCount3] = (textContent[loopCount2 - 1] - textContent[loopCount2]);
            loopCount3++;
            loopCount2++;
        }
        else if(inputI.contains("/")){
            partOfResult[loopCount3] = (textContent[loopCount2 - 1] / textContent[loopCount2]);
            loopCount3++;
            loopCount2++;
        }
        else if(inputI.contains("*")){
            partOfResult[loopCount3] = (textContent[loopCount2 - 1] * textContent[loopCount2]);
            loopCount3++;
            loopCount2++;
        }
        else if(inputI.contains("^")){
            partOfResult[loopCount3] = (Math.pow(textContent[loopCount - 1], textContent[loopCount]));
            loopCount3++;
            loopCount2++;
        }
        if(inputScan.hasNext() == false){
            double[] answer = new double[1000];
            for(int i = 0; i <= loopCount3;){
                answer[i] = partOfResult[i] + partOfResult[i+1];
                i++;
            }

            double sum = DoubleStream.of(answer).sum();
            System.out.println("The answer is " + sum);
            break;
        }   
    }       

    inputScan3.close();
    inputScan2.close();
    inputScan.close();
    inputNum.close();
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, I would recommend using a `Stack` as this is a pretty basic use case for `push` and `pop` operations.

Comment: Gotta say that it's a well written out first question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import java.lang.System;`

This is unnecessary.  `java.lang` is imported without you saying so, so you can already just write `System` in your code without this line.  You can safely remove it.

`Scanner inputScan2 = inputScan.useDelimiter("\\+|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\^|\\s");`

Just because `useDelimiter` returns a `Scanner` doesn't mean you need to put it into a variable.  You never use `inputScan2` again except to close it (and in any case, `inputScan2` is equal to `inputScan` after this line, making it redundant.)  So I would shorten the line to this:

`inputScan.useDelimiter("\\+|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\^|\\s");`

and also remove the corresponding line that closes this unused scanner.

It's kind of weird to have `loopCount2` and `loopCount3` as separate variables when they're always just one away from each other.  It seems like you could get rid of one of them.

I notice you don't have any methods except the main method.  That's not so bad for a relatively small program, but it's best to get into the habit of splitting your code up into methods.

I notice you don't have any code comments.  Comments often help you (and others) understand your code.  Especially when the variables are named things like `inputScan3` - that name gives a very general idea of the variable, but it doesn't really say why it's different from `inputScan`, for example.  Comments would help with that.

A line like `if(inputI.contains("+")){` is never going to be much good for compound statements - you're checking whether the entire String contains a `+`, which is not all that relevant if you're processing `4+2*3` because that doesn't tell you whether you're currently doing the addition or the multiplication.  You're pretty much going to have to redo the way you check which operation you are doing if you want to handle compound statements.

I notice you set your `answer` array to a size of 1000.  This is perhaps understandable with your other arrays because you don't know their size when you create them, but for this one, you already know the size - it's `loopCount3 + 1`.  So you can write `double[] answer = new double[loopCount3+1];` and save some memory.

Comment: I'll probably have to make the code for compound statements being sequential by each character or something (so more and more loops)...or maybe some sort of nested switch statement? Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would split the code. I see a class that works with the input and return an object with operands and operation, some kind of smart Stack that understands the input syntax. I see a class that could process your stacked object and could call methods for the operations needed.

Your main will be something like this then

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    System.out.println("What would you like to calculate?");
    Scanner inputNum = new Scanner(System.in);
    OperationsStack operations = new OperationBuilder(inputNum).build();
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    Double result = calculator.compute(operations);
    System.out.println("The answer is " + result);
}
```

EDIT: See [polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) to get some ideas about how to handle the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
package demo;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a, b, c;
    char z;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the First number");
    a = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Select the opearator : +,-,*,/");
    z = sc.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter the second number");
    b = sc.nextDouble();
    switch (z) {
    case '+':
      c = a + b;
      System.out.println("The sum is " + c);
      break;
    case '-':
      c = a - b;
      System.out.println("The difference is " + c);
      break;
    case '*':
      c = a * b;
      System.out.println("The Product is " + c);
      break;
    case '/':
      c = a / b;
      System.out.println("The Quotient is " + c);
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Invalid Operator Used");
      sc.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).